# How to select next available day at current month and year selenium js

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to fill out a signup form using selenium js. But I can't inspect the calendar because it opens like [this][1]. So I decided to send the date as a text while I'm sending other inputs to the form.

```
    $form = $crawler->filter('[data-track=\'signup-submit\'][data-input=\'signup-button\']')->form();
    $form['name'] = 'Test';
    $form['email'] = "{$faker->email}";
    $form['password'] = getenv('PASSWORD');
    $form['date'] = '30';
    $form['cityId'] = '2';
    $client->submit($form);
```

But in this case, I can only send specific days and months, not able to send years. So it is not an elegant solution even if I can send the year. So I thought the best solution will be to select the next available day on the calendar. But I don't know how to do it. Appreciate it if you have any thoughts on it. Thanks in advance.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WakwM.png